# Matching a substring in the column data frame to another column dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, substring

I have two dataframes, the first one like:

```
col1  col2
Apple  is the type of fruits
Banana yellow type of fruits
```

The second dataframe like:

```
colu1  colu2
red apple  red type
yellow banana  type of fruits
green lettuce  not a fruit
```

What I need is take a substring each rows of colu2 in dataframe2 and compare it to the substring col2 in dataframe1 and ignoring the word "of fruits"

So, as a result; I should have:

```
col1  col2  col3
red apple  red type  is the type of fruits
red apple  red type  yellow type of fruits
yellow banana  type of fruits  is the type of fruits
yellow banana  type of fruits  yellow type of fruits
```

It's quite confusing for me of how to do it, any help with that please?

Comment: Your question is quite confusing. What are you comparing here? it seems the only things you are checking is where "not a fruit" is in col2 for each row in the second dataframe?

Comment: I take each substring except "of fruits" in the second column of df2 and compare it to the second column of df1 if they match, so for example "not a fruit" in the 3rd row of df2 cannot match any of the substring in df1 (so we don't return it back) @Akaisteph7